# How basses are reconstructed on small speakers

Tags: analog

Not sure I'm in the right StackExchange group for this question, but it seems linked enough. Let me know if it's not the case.

I heard about an acoustic and/or signal processing technique that allows small speakers to kind of fake low bass sound waves, and that would allegedly be used by most good quality bluetooth speakers nowadays.

I wonder:

- what is this technique?
- do the sound waves it produces have the same quality and nature as the ones that could natively be produced by huge speakers?

Comment: If there were such a thing as an acoustics stackexchange, this would be a good question to ask there.  There are some tricks that can be played acoustically to make a speaker act bigger than it is (Bose was active in this area back in the 1990's, I think, and they still seem to be the best ones at it).  Certainly the bass response of teeny speakers got a _lot_ better after Bose showed that it could be done -- but that's about all I know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acoustic efficiency of a small speaker drops drastically with frequency. The standard way of dealing with this is to simply boost the bass through a linear EQ. However that's limited by the physical constraints of the speaker: power, driver excursion, port noise, etc.

There used to be techniques to create "fake" bass. That done by band-splitting the signal and running the low frequency band through a non-linear distortion, high-passing the result and adding it back the high frequency band.

Example: let's say you have a speaker that goes down to 90 Hz and you feed it a 50 Hz sine wave. If you don't do anything, the 50 Hz sine wave is just gone. The algorithm would run the 50Hz through a non-linearity and crete harmonics at 100Hz, 150Hz, 200Hz, etc and the harmonics would be played back. So at least something comes out and it could be identified as a 50Hz note since the spacing between the harmonics is still 50 Hz

> do the sound waves it produces have the same quality and nature as the ones that could natively be produced by huge speakers?

Not at all. It sounds pretty bad.

> would allegedly be used by most good quality bluetooth speakers nowadays.

Nope. Good quality and "fake bass" do not go together well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was an usage of the [missing fundamental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_fundamental) phenomenon? The basic idea is that if you pick some frequency $f$, even if your signal contains just some of its overtones $(f_1, f_2, f_3, ...)$, but not $f$ itself, your brain will still "listen" your signal as if $f$ were a part of it.

I'm not sure how common it's to exploit it in order to enhance bass frequencies for playback in small speakers, but the same wikipedia article I linked points out there's been at least [one patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5930373) in the late 80s which proposed synthesizing such overtones in order to induce the perception of low frequencies, as well as an [audio plugin](https://www.waves.com/plugins/maxxbass#adding-deep-low-frequencies-with-maxxbass) implementation.